# ML.Net issue with context.Transforms.Conversion getting schema mismatch error

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm trying to create a churn prediction model. Here is a sample data and the headers.
UserId,Gender,NoofLogin,TotalSpending,NumOfPurchases,HaveBaby,HaveOlderBaby,IsOld,IsNew,IsReferred,IsChurned
F559E0FF-6F6A-4C6C-B14F-000048FCB496,1,93,598.48,6,0,1,1,0,1,1
E47D014B-B8BF-42BF-BDDD-0000773FC965,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
62F58C2F-6AFE-455A-9D51-000141DAE1A3,1,7,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1

and here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Trainers.FastTree;

namespace MLNET_test_v1
{
    class Program
    {
        //UserId,IsFemale,nooflogin,recepval,no_of_receipts,HaveBaby,HaveOlderBaby,IsOld,IsNew,IsReferred,IsChurned
        //F559E0FF-6F6A-4C6C-B14F-000048FCB496,1,93,598.48,6,0,1,1,0,1,1
        public class ChurnData
        {
            [LoadColumn(0)] public string UserId;
            [LoadColumn(1)] public bool Gender;
            [LoadColumn(2)] public float NoofLogin;
            [LoadColumn(3)] public float TotalSpending;
            [LoadColumn(4)] public float NumOfPurchases;
            [LoadColumn(5)] public bool HaveBaby;
            [LoadColumn(6)] public bool HaveOlderBaby;
            [LoadColumn(7)] public bool IsOld;
            [LoadColumn(8)] public bool IsNew;
            [LoadColumn(9)] public bool IsReferred;
            [LoadColumn(10)] public bool IsChurned;
        }

        // Define a prediction class to hold the predicted values
        public class ChurnPrediction
        {
            [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
            public bool IsChurned;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a new MLContext
            var context = new MLContext();

            string base_folder = @"C:\Users\evren\Documents\PK\data\";
            string path = base_folder + "churn_1000.txt";
            // Load data from a text file (replace with your data source)
            // Define the text loader options
            var textLoaderOptions = new TextLoader.Options()
            {
                Separators = new[] { ',' }, // Specify the column separator
                HasHeader = true,           // Indicate that the first row contains headers
                AllowQuoting = true        // Enable quoting of fields
            };
            var data = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ChurnData>(path, textLoaderOptions);

            // Split the data into training and testing sets
            var split = context.Data.TrainTestSplit(data);

            // Define the data preprocessing pipeline
            var dataPipeline = context.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "IsChurned")
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("Gender"))
                .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("NoofLogin"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("TotalSpending"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("NumOfPurchases"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("HaveBaby"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("HaveOlderBaby"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("IsOld"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("IsNew"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("IsReferred"))
             .Append(context.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Gender", "NoofLogin", "TotalSpending", "NumOfPurchases", "HaveBaby", "HaveOlderBaby", "IsOld", "IsNew", "IsReferred"))
             .AppendCacheCheckpoint(context);

            // Train a Logistic Regression model
            var logisticRegressionPipeline = dataPipeline.Append(context.BinaryClassification.Trainers.LbfgsLogisticRegression());
            var logisticRegressionModel = logisticRegressionPipeline.Fit(split.TrainSet);

            // Train a Decision Tree model
            var options = new FastTreeBinaryTrainer.Options
            {
                // Use L2Norm for early stopping.
                EarlyStoppingMetric = EarlyStoppingMetric.L2Norm,
                // Create a simpler model by penalizing usage of new features.
                FeatureFirstUsePenalty = 0.1,
                // Reduce the number of trees to 50.
                NumberOfTrees = 50
            };


            var decisionTreePipeline = dataPipeline.Append(context.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree(options));
            var decisionTreeModel = decisionTreePipeline.Fit(split.TrainSet);

            // Make predictions using the Logistic Regression model
            var logisticRegressionPredictions = logisticRegressionModel.Transform(split.TestSet);
            var logisticRegressionMetrics = context.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(logisticRegressionPredictions);

            Console.WriteLine("Logistic Regression Model Metrics:");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Accuracy: {logisticRegressionMetrics.Accuracy}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  AUC: {logisticRegressionMetrics.AreaUnderRocCurve}");
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Make predictions using the Decision Tree model
            var decisionTreePredictions = decisionTreeModel.Transform(split.TestSet);
            var decisionTreeMetrics = context.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(decisionTreePredictions);

            Console.WriteLine("Decision Tree Model Metrics:");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Accuracy: {decisionTreeMetrics.Accuracy}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  AUC: {decisionTreeMetrics.AreaUnderRocCurve}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I get -> : 'Schema mismatch for input column 'Gender': expected vector or scalar of Single or Double, got Boolean (Parameter 'inputSchema')'

If I remove the bool columns (Gender, HasBaby..etc) from the Append rows, then I get->: 'Concatenated columns should have the same type. Column 'NoofLogin' has type of Single, but expected column type is Boolean.'

What is the correct way to do this?

If I remove the bool columns (Gender, HasBaby..etc) from the Append rows, then I get->: 'Concatenated columns should have the same type. Column 'NoofLogin' has type of Single, but expected column type is Boolean.'

What is the correct way to do this?